# How to convert -99 value in datetime column to a date of my choosing?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, if-statement

I have some data:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2 | 2021-05-01 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 |
| 4 | -99 |
| 5 | -99 |
| 6 | 2017-11-21 |
| 7 | -99 |
| 8 | 2019-02-04 |
| 9 | -99 |
| 10 | -99 |

Where I have -99, I want to change it to 2021-05-20.  I have tried if statement but it won't work, there are still -99s.  I have made sure it is a datetime column although thinking about that -99 isn't a datetime value.  Maybe that is where I'm going wrong?

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

if (df['Date'] is '-99'):
    df['Date'] = pd.Series(['2021-05-20' for x in range(len(df.index))])
```

I'm thinking the length part is wrong too, since there aren't as many -99 as there are data rows.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you try [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)?

Answer (score 1):

A [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html#pandas-series-mask) option:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].mask(df['Date'].eq('-99'), '2021-05-20')
```

A [`np.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas-dataframe-where) option:

```
df['Date'] = np.where(df['Date'].eq('-99'), '2021-05-20', df['Date'])
```

A [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) option:

```
df.loc[df['Date'].eq('-99'), 'Date'] = '2021-05-20'
```

A [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) option:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace({'-99': '2021-05-20'})
```

---

Convert to DateTime Option via [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) + [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna) credit to [@Nk03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724316/how-to-convert-99-value-in-datetime-column-to-a-date-of-my-choosing/67724399#comment119706518_67724399):

```
df['Date'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce').fillna(pd.to_datetime('2021-05-20'))
)
```

Comment: You can add one more option - pd.to_datetime with 'coerce' and then fill nan with required values.
.